How do I (or, can I) make DbContextFactory available for a class when the latter is used by a static class?
While converting an application to .NET Core, I’m adding also DI. One of the Html Helpers (a static class) accesses the data access layer (DAL). The latter requires the DbContextFactory as a parameter.
public static class MyHtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlContent MyHelper(this IHtmlHelper helper, …)
    {
        //How do I go about defining _factory, given that this class is static?
        DbContextFactory<MyContext> _factory = new();

        //The serviceProvider argument is missing here, hence compiler error CS7036)
        DALsomething _dal = new DALsomething(_factory);
    }
}

Program.cs:
var _ConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbConnectionString");
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<MyContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(_ConnectionString), ServiceLifetime.Scoped);

The DAL base class:
public abstract class dalBaseClass
{
    public readonly IDbContextFactory<MyContext> _factory;
    public dalBaseClass(IDbContextFactory<MyContext> dbContextFactory)
    {
        _factory = dbContextFactory;
    }
}

How do I (or, can I)  make DbContextFactory available for a DAL class when it is used by a static class?

is it ok for you to add more params to MyHelper?

Although you can, you shouldn't. HTML extensions should know nothing about the database. Any data rendered to HTML should be queried separately and passed as a parameter to the extension method.

@Roman Marusyk, Yes

could you show us how MyHelper is called? did you try to pass IHttpContextAccessor?

Given an IHtmlHelper instance, you can access helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.RequestServices to access the DI scope for the current request, which you could use to resolve your injected services. But, as phuzi said, your helper is almost certainly doing too much.

@RomanMarusyk This is proprietary code. I hope the following is of help:
IHtmlContent _Link = helper.DrilldownLink( /*A list of parameters*/);

Why are you doing this? This is a really bad design. BTW the "data layer" is inside DbContext. EF is an ORM and returns an entire graph of related objects, not table rows, at a time. The DbContext is a Unit-of-Work which is why you always see it defined in using blocks or as a scoped service. Trying to use it like that in a static HTML helper is simply wrong

@Hayee This is proprietary code that means very little, especially for commonly used code ... or bugs, in this case. Data reading goes in the Controller actions, not the View rendering code. Nothing prevents you from posting how you intend to use this snippet. That's the only way people can tell you how to get access to the registered DbContext or DbContextFactory through IServiceProvider.

I absolutely agree with the comments. My Html helpers deal only with the presentation of data accepted in view models. Except, that there is one, single logic, which cannot be resolved at the time the view model is created.
If I would access the database for the business data, that would be a big no-no.

"Except, that there is one, single logic, which cannot be resolved at the time the view model is created." Ah, is this is an attempt to resolve the business logic limitation?

@phuzi, This is not business logic. It is technical.
I am sorry that I do not provide enough information to the people who generously spend their time on this. I was searching high and low for the last week or so. I guess that the reason for not finding a solution is that there is none, except antipatterns.
Based on the responses, I shall redesign. Wish me luck.

While agreeing with the "don't do this" sentiment, passing it as an argument is a good choice because it exposes the weird dependency on a DbContextFactory. Another option is not to make the class static. Make it an instance and inject the DbContextFactory into it.

..but if you've decided to redesign, that's way better. Sometimes we have a problem like this and we know it's solveable, but the problem itself is wrong. The best thing is to figure out how not have that problem in the first place. There's always a way.
